# After editing the animation in the blender, the animation and avatar rigs in Unity do not match

Tags: .fbx

I have a ready-made animation (without a mesh).  I needed to change the length of the animation itself, crop a few frames.
After exporting the edited animation back to Unity, the program itself issues an error of inconsistencies in the hierarchies of bones. After checking, I found that the Blender adds the name of the skeleton to the beginning of the hierarchy of bones.
[image][image]